# How to log in in chat with existing account

Tags: support, chat

I am a member of physics stack exchange and am able to access my account in it. But after chat was enabled on my account I could not log in as it said my account didn't exist. At the same time I am already logged in in the physics site of stack exchange

Comment: The Physics.SE account doesn't work. Make an account on Chat.SE. Shouldn't this be status-bydesign? .

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have [the requisite reputation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/privileges/chat) (and had it at the time this question was posted, too), so it should just work. Can you try again. Possibly the chat system didn't notice right away that you had enough rep.

If that fails I'm out of my depth and we'll look for someone who knows more.

Answer (score 0):

Which login type do you use? OpenID? SE account? Google account? Which?

Comment: They're all OpenID logins, actually.

Comment: Yeah, but they involve different mechanisms and thus go wrong differently.

Comment: The only thing that differs is the OpenID provider, but to the best of my knowledge there is nothing different in the actual authentication mechanism on SE's end.